# Uniform distribution over area of a dartboard vs over distance from center

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

A bad player hits a dartboard represented by the unit circle with uniform probability over its area, and a good player has uniform distance distribution over [0,1].

But what's the difference between the two, if every point in the circle is some measure of distance away based on the radius?

Comment: But area is $\pi r^2$. $r^2$ vs. $r$ makes a difference, no?

Comment: For a unit circle, there is more area between $0.75$ and $1$ than between $0$ and $0.25$. Distance is same in both cases $0.25$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that the bad player lands in some region of the dart board is equal to the area of the region divided by $\pi$. So the probability that the bad player lands in the circle of radius $r$ (where $r < 1$) is $\frac{\pi r^2}{\pi} = r^2$. The probability that the good player lands in the circle of radius $r$ is $r$, since her distance to the center is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

The bad player has probability $\frac34$ of being more than half the radius away from the middle.  The good player has probability $\frac12$ of being that far away.

Similarly at different points.  So the good player is likely to be better than the bad player, at least if they throw independently.